# Java - Handling Errors from concrete classes that implement 1 interface

Tags: java, exception

In our code we have a number of processors that implement the same interface.
By using spring and some arguments in our code, we lookup the correct concrete implementation of the IMsgProcessorInbound class to call.

When an exception occurs in any of these concrete implementations, i would like to catch the expception in the below try catch block.

Unforunately, this try catch block is never entered when an exception is thrown in the concrete implementation.

Is there any way I can catch the exceptions in the catch block listed below instead of littering all my concrete implementations with exception handling code?
Or is there some error handling functionality that spring can provide me?

```
IMsgProcessorInbound msgProcessor = msgProcessorSelectorInbound.lookupProcessorInbound(args);


    try {
        msgProcessor.processMsg(fixProcessorArgs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception is: " + e);
    }
```

All help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Damien

Comment: Where is that try/catch block located in your code?

Comment: Hi Daniel. It is located in the class that handles which processor to call. E.g. if arg is a - lookup and call processor A, if arg is b, lookup and call processor b

Comment: I do not think you can do this, unless you use some kind of factory pattern. First I will make all the methods throw exception, and then I will call a factory method, that will decide on which method to call, based on a type parameter. This will provide me a mechanism of centralizing the error handling.

Comment: I can assure you that any `Exception` thrown by `msgProcessor.processMsg` would indeed be caught there.  Is it possible that the "exception" being thrown is not in fact an instance of `java.lang.Exception` but is an `Error` (or some direct subclass of `Throwable`) instead?  Not that you *should* catch these in general, but this would explain why they get past your `catch` block.  Otherwise, the exception must be thrown from a different part of the code; have a careful look at its stacktrace.

Comment: Make sure you are not having any try catch blocks in your concrete classes. also, are these exceptions currently thrown out or go un detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this;

```
  try {
        msgProcessor.processMsg(fixProcessorArgs);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("Exception is: " + e);
    }
```

msgProcessor.processMsg() may not be throwing a type of Exception. The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions. So the above should catch both checked and unchecked exceptions.

If you can't still get into the catch block - then the msgProcessor.processMsg() may be swallowing exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Can't really give a full answer without knowing more about the problem. What Exception subclass is not getting caught by the try/catch block?

In other words, you state the following:

> Unforunately, this try catch block is never entered when an exception is thrown in the concrete implementation.

How do you know this, and what `Exception` is it that isn't being caught? What is the contract that your `processMsg` method fulfills (the method signature on the interface)? Does it declare which `Exception`s it will throw? If so, which ones?

For the `Exception`s that are thrown, do you have a stack trace? If so, is it definitely the line `msgProcessor.processMsg(fixProcessorArgs);` which is throwing the `Exception`?

It may also be that, for whatever reason, you need to catch `Throwable` in your `catch`, rather than `Exception`. If you look at the inheritance hierarchy for [Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), you should note that it implements `Throwable` which is in turn implemented by a number of concrete `Error` classes. At the moment, your code will not catch any `Error`'s thrown in the try/catch block.

Answer (score 1):

If all your implementation classes should have this maybe it is better to declare a throws and handle the exception one level up in the stack trace.

Updated to reflect a comment from Daniel. Declare a throws in the interface and eclipse will highlight with compiler error where you should put the try catch

Comment: I think that's what he's trying to do.